# Excel Add-In not working in French Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I have developed an Add-in for excel using VB .NET and ExcelDNA.
The Add-In works on my computer and all computers which has an english version of excel.
However, it does not work on my clients computer(is in English) which has a French version of Excel.

I get the following error:

**Old Format or invalid type library** HResult 0x80028018

I have spent hours on the internet and the solution I found was that you need to change the
Culture Info.
 I added this to my code does not seem to work,

```
        Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = _
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
         New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR")
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only solution I found was to convert my whole project to .NET 4.0, and now it works fine.